# Triggering workflow via javascript not working

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, workflow

I'm not super familiar with javascript and how it interacts with SharePoint, but I was tasked with starting a workflow on several items with one click. I did some research and found [this](http://tomislavspadmin.blogspot.com/2016/11/start-workflow-on-multiple-items-at.html) which walked me through everything step by step.

I ended up with this code and have added the two jquery files into the SharePoint site.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="...JS/StartWorkflow/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="...JS/StartWorkflow/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function StartWFOnSelectedItems()
{
    var listName = "NewArrivalInformation";
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
    var url = document.URL;
    var item;
    for (item in selectedItems)
    {
        var itemId = selectedItems[item].id;
        url = url.split(listName)[0];
        url = url+listName+'/'+itemId+'_.000';
        StartWorkflow(url,itemId);
    // alert("Workflow initiated");
    }
    alert("Workflow started on selected items");
}


function StartWorkflow(ItemURL,ItemID)
 {
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "StartWorkflow",
        item: ItemURL,
        templateId: "{6eb308a5-46e3-4673-8b20-e3c7c1d37658}",
        workflowParameters: "<root />",
        completefunc: function() 
        {
            alert(ItemID);      
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Obviously, I usually have the full links at the top, but I've taken the first part of it out for privacy reasons. I believe I linked everything in my site correctly, because when I click the button I've added, I get the alerts listed within the script and within both of the functions, meaning they're being triggered. However, the workflow doesn't run. I have checked multiple times that the template ID is correct, and I'm at a loss as to where this could be going wrong. The workflow runs when I trigger it the normal way (through the workflows button), but running it using this script does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.workflowservices.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/SP.Runtime.js"></script>
<script>
  SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', init);
  function init() {
    $.getScript(SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('sp.js'), function () {
      $.getScript(SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('sp.workflowservices.js'), function () {
        StartWorkflow("workflow subscription id","","site url");
      });
    });
  }
  //dialog element to show during processing
  var dlg = null;
  //Subscription id – Workflow subscription id
  //list item id for which to start workflow. If site workflow, then send null for itemId
  //SiteURL – site collection where the workflow exists
  function StartWorkflow(subscriptionId, itemId, SiteURL) {
    showInProgressDialog();
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(SiteURL);
    var wfManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(ctx, ctx.get_web());
    var subscription = wfManager.getWorkflowSubscriptionService().getSubscription(subscriptionId);
    ctx.load(subscription, 'PropertyDefinitions');
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
      function (sender, args) {
        var params = new Object();
        //Find initiation data to be passed to workflow.
        var formData = subscription.get_propertyDefinitions()["FormData"];
        if (formData != null &&   formData != 'undefined' &&   formData != "") {
      var assocParams = formData.split(";#");
      for (var i = 0; i < assocParams.length; i++) {
        params[assocParams[i]] = subscription.get_propertyDefinitions()[assocParams[i]];
      }
    }
    if (itemId) {
      wfManager.getWorkflowInstanceService().startWorkflowOnListItem(subscription, itemId, params);
    }
    else {
      wfManager.getWorkflowInstanceService().startWorkflow(subscription, params);
    }
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
      function (sender, args) {
        closeInProgressDialog(SiteURL);
      },
      function (sender, args) {
        closeInProgressDialog(SiteURL);
        $('#msg')[0].innerHTML = "Woops – something went wrong, the document may have already been reviewed";
      }
    );
  },
  function (sender, args) {
    closeInProgressDialog(SiteURL);
    $('#msg')[0].innerHTML = "Woops – something went wrong, the document may have already been reviewed";
  }
);
}

  function closeInProgressDialog(SiteURL) {
    if (dlg != null) {
      dlg.close();
      $('#msg')[0].innerHTML = "Thank you – you can now close the page";
    }
  }
  function showInProgressDialog() {
    if (dlg == null) {
      dlg = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose("Please wait…", "Waiting for workflow…", null, null);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Source:https://spdeveloper.co.uk/blog/2018/09/01/starting-a-sharepoint-workflow-via-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with using a different third party library, you could use my lib called [SharepointPlus](https://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/), then you can replace the use of JQuery and SPServices.

I'll assume you're using "Sharepoint 2010" for the workflow platform type (the most reliable ones) – [see the documentation](https://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/lists.html#startWorkflow).
It's also possible to use a "Sharepoint 2013" for the workflow platform type ([see the documentation](https://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/lists.html#startWorkflow2013)).
[image: screenshot of the platform type selection for workflows]

A couple of requirements:

1. Your workflow needs to have the option to be manually started
   [image: screenshot of the option "Allow this workflow to be manually started"]
2. The current user needs to have enough rights to trigger the workflow

Then the code will look like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sharepointplus/browser/sharepointplus.js"></script>
<script>
function StartWFOnSelectedItems() {
  var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
  for (var item in selectedItems) {
    // I'll suppose "selectedItems[item].id" is the item ID
    var itemID = selectedItems[item].id;
    $SP().list("NewArrivalInformation").startWorkflow({
      ID:itemID,
      workflowName:"Name of the workflow to start"
    })
    .then(function() {
      console.log("Workflow completed for "+itemID);
    })
    .catch(function() {
      console.error("Workflow failed for "+itemID);
    })
  }
}
</script>
```